# When should I use Compiled LINQ vs Normal LINQ

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I just read up on a performance of LINQ, and there is a HUGE amount to be gained by using Compiled LINQ.

Now, why won't I always use compiled LINQ?

Comment: Does this apply to all LINQ expressions or just LINQ to SQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: when it's only going to happen once in a long time.

[Long Answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2008/01/14/performance-quiz-13-linq-to-sql-compiled-query-cost-solution.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should use it when some linq query is executing most of the time. Those can be converted to compiled lynq. Performance will be improved as execution path of query will be set at compile time. I used it in my project and performance went up a notched.